# Are book recommendation questions not allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

Example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659740/book-recommendations-for-moodle-2-2

Are these types of questions not allowed?

Seems like something very useful for Moodle developers. Wouldn't Google pick up this question?

Answer (score 13):

Recommendation questions in general aren't allowed because they're just that: recommendations.  Since there's no real *right* answer, they tend to generate lots of discussion and don't really fit the StackOverflow Q&A format.

Recommendation questions are pretty much the poster child for the **not constructive** close reason:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

This isn't to say that recommendation questions can't be interesting or valuable, just that StackOverflow isn't the place for them.  It's a pity that there isn't some obvious great place for them, but that's the price of keeping StackOverflow great for its core function of providing answers to concrete programming problems.